# Meteor autoform with user registration and login

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-autoform

Is there a way to use the autoform package with the accounts package? I have collection2 installed so I'm guessing I would need to attach a schema?

I created both templates for the signup form and login form. Any help would be appreciated, just trying to grasp Meteor development.

Ps. I'm using the iron-cli if that makes any difference

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do it manually but there is an awesome user registration and login package ready for use https://atmospherejs.com/useraccounts/core here is a demo http://useraccounts-bootstrap.meteor.com/

I will advice against going to do it manually it might take too much time to really combine accounts with autoform unless it was done already you can search for a package at https://atmospherejs.com/ hopefully it's helpful. I use useraccounts and I don't see the need to really create it by myself ;)

Comment: I wanted to use this https://github.com/Planifica/meteor-wizard/ for a multipage signup form.